# Creating map of New Mexico where deaf people live in county from US Census database?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, census, united-states

I would like to get some feedback from those who have been doing or perform on US Census Map.

Is there a way for me to get information on Deaf person living in New Mexico. Would US Census be helpful?

On the other hand, do I need to find more information from the state of New Mexico?

I wanted to show a map of where each county where a deaf person lives? Is that possible or is it the word "deaf" too broad to be included in the US Census database?

Comment: RyanDalton, Got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think I can directly link, but what you want is American Community Survey Table S1810 with New Mexico County Geography.
Start here:

http://factfinder2.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/searchresults.xhtml?refresh=t

Enter S1810 for your search topic. This should give you four tables named Disability Characteristics.

From the options on the left, now select "Geographies".

- For geographic type, select County.
- State, select New Mexico.
- Lastly select "All Counties within New Mexico" and then click "Add to Your Selections".
- In the top right corner of the Select Geographies
  popup, choose Close.

Now, pick the table of the four choices that you prefer. I would suggest 2010 ACS 3-year estimates, as it has data for the most counties. This will give you your table of results.

Click Download and use the default choice. This will give you a CSV file that you can use to create a dbf which you can join to county geometry to make your map. The CSV file is going to need considerable formatting before you can use it as a DBF.

Note that even with the 3-year estimates, there are only estimates for 20 of the 33 counties in New Mexico. In order to get estimated total population with a hearing disability, you need to add up these four columns:

```
VC04    HC02    EST
VC08    HC02    EST
VC015   HC02    EST
VC023   HC02    EST
```

Comment: Thank you. I took a look at this data and it is an interesting.